# How to Exclude Android-x From Android Dependency

Tags: android, duplicates, androidx

I am working on an old Android project which uses mostly old libraries.To integrate Firebase project I have added below firebase dependency

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.1.0' //this is creating problem
```

`firebase-database:9.4.0` is not creating any problem when i am using it without `firebase-ui-database` After integrating `firebase-ui-database:` it is creating `duplicate class` and `resource linking failed` errors.As I check in `gradlew app:dependencies` I found that `firebase-ui-database:` is using android-x library. To avoid this I have tried to exclude `Android-x` library but no luck. Below is the code that I have tried to exclude android-x

```
    implementation ('com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.1.0'){

    exclude group: 'com.firebaseui', module:'firebase-ui-common'
    exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module:'lifecycle-runtime'
    exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module:'lifecycle-common'
    exclude group: 'androidx.annotation', module:'annotation'
    exclude group: 'androidx.arch.core', module:'core-common'
    exclude group: 'androidx.annotation', module:'annotation'
    exclude group: 'androidx.arch.core', module:'core-common'
    exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module:'lifecycle-viewmodel'
    exclude group: 'androidx.core', module:'core'
    exclude group: 'android.support', module:'v4.app'
    exclude group: 'androidx.media', module:'media:1.0.0'
}
```

I also tried `package-options` to exclude android-x like below but not solving

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    exclude 'META-INF/androidx.exifinterface_exifinterface.version'

}
```

also tried disabling androidx in build.properties but still same

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```

I want to use old dependency.How can I still use `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database` without loading android-x library or creating class duplicate errors.

Comment: Use an older version of `firebase-ui-database`.

Comment: Thanks it solves android-x. Can you help on one more point pls   ` +--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0-alpha8
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0 -> 26.0.1` how can I force arch.core:common to use support-annotations:26.0.0